# Undefined reference on compile

Tags: c, extern, undefined-reference, variable-declaration

I am trying to use a variable I have already declared on a .h file on a .c file and i gives me a compile error:

> undefined reference to `var`

this is the mach.c content:

```
#include "machheader.h"

int 
main( void )
{
    var = 1;
    printf("Variable %d\n", var);
}
```

And my machheader.h contains only this:

`extern int var;`

Any idea?

Comment: If you use `extern` you have to (edit) _define_ the variable somewhere. Try adding `int var;` to your `.c` file outside of any function.

Comment: @Arc676 it already has a declaration, it needs definition.

Comment: `extern` means here "it is properly defined somehwere else". And the error tells you it isn't.

Comment: A global variable is a bad thing, a global variable called `var` is particularly bad.

Comment: @Clifford it's just an example here. Not using it as such in the real code. Thank you :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `int var;` is a _tentative definition at file-level. That would work very well.

Comment: @Olaf Absolutely sir. But I did not get the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case,

```
 extern int var;
```

is a *declaration*, not a definition. You need to have a definition of `var` in your code.

Comment: “a” in the sense of “exactly one.”

Answer (score 1):

"undefined reference" is a linker error rather than a compiler error.  You need to link the object code containing the instantiation of `var` which must be separately compiled or provided by a library.